# How to store GMaps API reverse geocoding response in MySQL (with PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-maps

I have a table with Venues that contain the following important columns: `venue_id (int), latitude (double), longitude (double)`. What would be proper way to store a GMAPS geocoding response in MySQL? Example response is JSON.
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true

I have following variants:

Create a table like `venue_reverse_geocoding` that has columns like `venue_id (int), json (blob), country (varchar), country_short (varchar), city (varchar), city_short (varchar), formatted_address (varchar)`

Or add a column to my `venues` table that has new column `json` and create a PHP class that parses the JSON every time I need the data and creates an object with the above semantic fields?

I know it's not a good question regarding its "this or that" but I really hope I will get argumented suggestion for one solution over the other.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's a better approach to store the details in separate columns to be able to search for a specific detail via SQL.

Related to google-geocoding it's the best when you don't store anything, because it's [**not permitted**](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en#section_10_1_3)